# Michael Hartl tutorial - Chapter 7 debugger not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have been struggling to figure out why the debugger won't display. I decided to keep going despite not getting this part to work. But then I also couldn't get the /users/1 to display any information, even though the route seemed to work...

So now I am going back to the initial problem, could anyone tell me where to double check to see why this isn't displaying?

However I have also included code concerned with my second issues - getting the users/1 to display expected information

The rails console correctly shows the user using User.first

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

custom.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}


/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $gray-medium-light;
  color: $gray-light;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-darker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}

/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'users/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'        

  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  resources :users

end
```

views/users/show.html.erb

```
    <%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
    <h1>
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <%= @user.name %>
    </h1>
```

User Controller - users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: did it working earlier ?

Comment: please post the error message being shown in the rails server

Comment: I am not getting any error. The content just does not display.
The de bugger (i believe) should appear on every page - but does not.
/users/1 route works, but also does not display expected contents

Comment: @dinosaurjohnson Did you ever get resolution on this? I tripped across this as I was having the same issue, but found my mix up was due to a very dumb PEBCAK issue. Have you tried just running `<%= debug(params) %>` absent any environment boolean to confirm you get the debug info at all?

Answer (score 1):

modify the debug line in "application.html.erb" to
<%= debug(params.to_yaml) if Rails.env.development? %>